# Hyperledger with different PKI than Fabric CA

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, x509certificate, hyperledger, pki

I am reading the docs and other information regarding using the hyperledger fabric and everywhere I see the Fabric CA.

I undertand the concept how it works and I also understand pretty well PKI.

Is it mandatory to use Fabric CA in order to provide identities in hyperledger? I do not see any reason why not to use any other deployed PKI in order to issue certificates and CRL to hyperledger peers, orderers, etc.

I tried to use it in developmen environment and private keys and certificates has standard format which can be produced by any PKI solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It's not mandatory to use Fabric CA. My network runs well with keys and certificates generated by other CA. For instance, you can generate all the materials by openssl.  By the way, it's worth noting that currently the Java/Node SDK only supports ECDSA algorithms (per my knowledge), you want to pay attention to the algorithms when generating keys and certificates from your CA.

Comment: Can you share a link or article how the alternative CA is communicated with?